# Difference of memory organization between iOS device and iPhone simulator

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management, ios-simulator

I'm trying to develop an app using Xcode 4.3.3 with iPhone 5.1 simulator.

When i run this app on simulator, i got no warnings and it's working very well. But,when i try to make this work on iOS device,i got an warning message which is **Received memory warnings**. I got this warning message while the app starts to display images on the screen. I'm using [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/) project which is available in github to display images.I think this problem is releated to how memory organization differs from iOS device to simulator. I have looked this question [How does building for iOS device and simulator actually differ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10205654/how-does-building-for-ios-device-and-simulator-actually-differ?rq=1) to see how the building app for iOS Device and Simulator differs. But,what i found about memory organization didn't satisfy me. Do you guys have any idea why this is happening ?

Another question : Is there any limitation for an application in the context of memory management? What i mean is, for example let's say 5MB memory is allocated ,will i get any messages which points to this issue ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will never get memory warnings in the simulator unless you create them yourself (with the "Simulate Memory Warning" option). You have access to the entire memory of the Mac, including virtual memory. You had better not run out with a mobile app...

If you're seeing memory warnings on device, it means you're using too much memory. The best tool for determining where you're having trouble is Instruments and specifically the Allocations instrument. This will show you what is taking the most memory and where you should focus. Most memory warnings are due to a leak or retain loop.

Answer (score 1):

you should better do not debug with the simulator , because the simulator`s memory is the mac , but your device`s memory is very limit , and the capability of the simulator is better