# Simulator Vs IOS Device Performance

Tags: iphone, xcode, performance, swift, ios-simulator

I'm creating a platform app which has ground nodes constantly moving, being disposed and regenerating. When running my app on the simulator a noticeable glitch in apparent, however when running on my device, from what I can see there is not glitch.

My question is, should the device perform better then the simulator or am I maybe just not noticing the glitch on the device because it is so much small.

Previous article have suggested the simulator should perform better, but these articles are in reference to iPhone 3GS, so I wondering if the newer iPhones are now out performing the simulator.

My device is an iPhone 5 and it is running IOS 8.2 and the simulator is version 8.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just general usage testing. The device performs in an entirely different environment than your computer, and it's the best way to make sure if you push your app out to devices, that nothing unexpected will happen. For example, the phone/pad may have limited data coverage, low memory situations, incoming calls etc.. These situations are a lot more common on devices, then when people emulate it though the simulator.

On a hardware point of view, the device uses a different processor architecture than your Mac, which also needs to be accounted for (not as much as other cases, but you need to cover your bases). The Mac also cannot reliably emulate RAM, Disc Space, Processor Speed etc...hence testing on the device is useful here also.

**Overall** if you're intending to release your application to the App Store, or to devices at least, it's worth testing on the device itself. Only then can you be sure that it will act and perform as expected on the platform you intend to target. The simulator is only a simulator after all, not the real thing!

Reference from [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13235702/testing-ios-testing-on-real-devices-vs-simulator).