# Does iPhone Simulator emulate memory ram space of different devices?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I need to test my app on an iPhone 3gs but I haven't the real device.
My app contains several functions that requires a large amount of use of the CPU. If I test the app on the simulator by setting the device hardware as "iPhone", does It emulate also the real memory space of the iPhone 3GS?
Can I rely in iPhone Simulator?

Comment: It's a simulator, not an emulator. The simulator has many differences. This is an example where the simulator is not a good test. You need real devices for this type of testing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. The simulator is unconstrained and has the CPU/Memory of your computer.

Some more interesting differences here: [iPhone device vs. iPhone simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/380062/iphone-device-vs-iphone-simulator)