# No sound in simulator of xcode 4.4.1 in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i created an AVaudioplayer application and builed succeed. but no sound is working in iphone 5.1 simulator in xcode4.4.1

thanx in advance

Comment: this question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/302399/sound-not-working-in-iphone-simulator/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this  might help.

Mac's System Preferences > Sound > Sound Effects uncheck(off) then check(on) the "Play user interface sound effects" , just check(on) it if its unchecked in default, reset it if its already checked.

Answer (score 0):

If checking the "Play user interface sound effects" in System Preferences does not work,

try making your instance of AVAudioPlayer a global variable.
This worked for me when I had the same issue when using the simulator.

you can also try calling

```
[audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
```

before

```
[audioPlayer play];
```