# Sound not playing in iOS Simulator. No errors

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have constructed some code that is supposed to play audio when a button is clicked. There are no errors in the code, but when I open the iOS Simulator and press the button, no sound plays. The button does the tap animation, but nothing happens. 
I have both the AVFoundation and AudioToolbox frameworks. 
I also have my audio file in resources. 
I am not using breakpoints. 
The button is set to use the 'playAudio:' first responder upon Touch Up Inside.

Here is my 'ViewController.h' file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;
- (IBAction)playAudio:(id)sender;

@end
```

And here is my 'ViewController.m' file:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (IBAction)playAudio:(id)sender {
    AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;
    NSString *audioPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"AudioFile" ofType:@"wav"];
    NSURL *audioURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:audioPath];
    audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:audioURL error:nil];
    [audioPlayer play];
    sleep(5);
};

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
@end
```

The audio segment is about 3 seconds.

Any help is much appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: Is your computer unmuted and the volume set high enough to hear?

Comment: did you try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12260120/no-sound-in-simulator-of-xcode-4-4-1-in-iphone?

Answer (score 1):

I am quite new to ios but I had the same problem and was able to fix it.

I simply declared my AVAudioPlayer variable as a global variable and called

```
[audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
```

before

```
[audioPlayer play];
```

Just calling prepareToPlay didnt fix it, I had to declare the global variable to for it to work.
Not sure why that makes a difference to the Simulator but it works now.

Answer (score 1):

**Play sound/music file in objective-c,
I had the same problem and was able to fix it with below code.**

```
.h  file

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

- (IBAction)actionOnPlayButton:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)actionOnStopButton:(id)sender;

- (void)playSound ;

@end

.m file



 #import "ViewController.h"

    @interface ViewController ()

    @end

    @implementation ViewController

    AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;

    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        self.title = @"Play Music";
    }

    -(void)playSound{

        NSString *soundFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sound10"
                                                                  ofType:@"mp3"];
        NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];
        audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFileURL error:nil];
        audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1;

        [audioPlayer prepareToPlay];

        [audioPlayer play];
    }



    - (IBAction)actionOnPlayButton:(id)sender {

        [self playSound];
    }
```

****Used above lines of code, it will work fine...
Note:-  Don't forget to import following framework:-**

#import 
    #import