# XCode 6 bug with AudioSystemSounds?

Tags: ios, xcode, audiotoolbox

As of yesterday after upgrading to XCode6 my AudioSystemSounds that were previously working now are silent. I have tried to reset my system sounds via an outdated answer ([Sound not working in iPhone Simulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/302399/sound-not-working-in-iphone-simulator)) through Settings/Sound/SoundEffects/Play user interface sounds but that hasn't worked.

There are no reported errors or crash, just silence.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is a bug in the IOS 8.0 simulator; try running on iOS 7.1 to verify system sounds are working - which will directly implicate the simulator.