# How to get audio on the Apple TV simulator?

Tags: audio, tvos

When I launch my app on the actual Apple TV, the sound comes out alright.
But I can't get the sound on the simulator.
There is an Audio Output in the Audio Video settings but it is empty.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try some of the solutions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/302399/2108547).