# Sound Plays on iPhone but not in simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-simulator, avaudioplayer

I have an app that works completely fine on several different iPhones(5s,6,6s) with different iOS versions but doesn't play sound on simulator(simulator plays sound on safari but not in app).I don't think i have any coding issue such an initialize or such things because it works fine in physical device.
please help me out.

- I've used AVAudioPlayer.
- I've checked out all of the answers in the following  link but it didn't work
  for me. [Sound not working in iPhone    Simulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/302399/sound-not-working-in-iphone-simulator)
- I use Xcode Version 9.4.1 and iOS 11.4 on simulator

Comment: Do you have any error in the log? Do you use a MacMini or MacPro?

Comment: No nothing special. Anyway... I compiled it on debug mode and suddenly simulator began playing the sound...!!