# iPhone simulator not playing audio using AVFoundation with ambient AVAudioSession

Tags: ios, swift, optimization, audio, avfoundation

**Background**

I am using Xcode 14.2 and Swift 5 to play audio using `import AVFoundation` in an iPad and iPhone app.

The default audio session category is `.soloAmbient` so I added the below `.ambient` code to `viewDidLoad()` to allow audio from other apps to mix while audio is playing in my app.

`try? AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.ambient)`

**Results**

Testing my app on various devices and the iPhone simulators give a surprising result:

✅ iPad device 12.5 - Yes audio

✅ iPad simulator 16.2 - Yes audio

✅ iPhone device 16.2 - Yes audio

✅ iPhone simulator 14.2 - Yes audio

❌ iPhone simulator 16.2 - No audio

❌ iPhone simulator 16.4 - No audio

✅ Mac (iPad) simulator - Yes audio

**Question**

Why are multiple iPhone simulators producing no audio?

Could this be a bug specifically with iPhone simulator?

Can I simply trust the good result from an actual iPhone device and ignore the unexpected result from the iPhone simulator?

Any insights appreciated! Thanks. :-)

Comment: See the answer to [Sound not working in iPhone Simulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76269088/20386264)

Comment: Many thanks for the tip, Benzy Neez.

Answer (score 0):

> Could this be a bug specifically with iPhone simulator?

It's a behavior, not a bug. The Simulator is not expected to act just like a device with regard to audio and audio sessions.

> Can I simply trust the good result from an actual iPhone device and ignore the unexpected result from the iPhone simulator?

Yes.

> Mac simulator - Yes audio

There is no such thing as a Mac simulator.

Comment: Thanks, although it does raise the question of what is the point of the simulator if it’s not expected to act just like the device. Seems some very strange buggy behavior that paying Apple Developer customers are getting where the iPhone simulator is producing an incorrect result compared to the iPad simulator, Mac simulator*, and device.
* “Mac simulator” as in building the app in Xcode and running the iPadOS version directly in macOS.

Comment: I stand by what I said in my answer. And I disagree with everything you just said. After all, development on the simulator is free! What you're paying all that money for is exactly the ability to run on a device. And the Mac "simulator" is still not a simulator; you are running the app, itself, directly.

Comment: @user4806509 Remember, it's a simulator, not an emulator. The iOS simulator has MANY differences from a real iOS device. The simulator is fine for basic UI testing and basic code logic. But real devices must be used for final testing before sending an app to the App Store. This is especially true for verifying any hardware features like audio input/output, GPS, camera, etc. Even the file system is very different. The simulator lets you write to the app bundle. Can't do that on a real device. The simulator file system is (usually) case-insensitive. Device is case-sensitive.

Comment: Thanks, HangarRash, I do understand there are some differences between device and simulator capability. For instance, the Apple developer documentation indicates limitations for the camera on the simulator, but the documentation doesn’t seem to outline limitations for AVAudioSession. There is a notable discrepancy between iOS simulator and iPadOS simulator where `.soloAmbient` works as expected but `.ambient` does not.

Comment: I mistyped on that occasion. I meant I'd delete my answer. Which indeed I may have done, I forget. — And I'm not defending Apple or the Simulator. I'm helping you face reality, a practice which constitutes much of the art of programming. The device is a reliable test milieu in ways that the Simulator just isn't. That's a well known fact. And now you know it too.

Comment: You have a recollection that is different to what actually happened. I pointed out that your answer failed to compile and that your explanation wasn’t clear. No big issue. But rather than attempt to clarify or correct, you threatened to delete the entire question.

Comment: Just an update on this question, I’ve run more tests on other iPhone simulators, and indeed this is an issue specific to the iOS 16 simulators. There are no details in the Apple documentation about new AVAudioSession behaviors for `.ambient` on iOS and iPadOS. This appears a clear issue of a buggy simulator.